# How do you turn string values into columns in unpivot statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im trying write an unpivot query that turns User data stored in columns into one row per user. Heres what I have so far, thanks to other SO posts: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fa77c/2

Error (makes sense because "email" is a string stored in the Name column):

> Invalid column name 'email'.

End goal:

```
ID Email   Phone
1  a@a.com 111
2  b@b.com 222
3  NULL    333
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure that unpivot is really what you want here. You can do this pretty easily with some aggregation.

```
select ac.AccountID
    , max(case when c.Name = 'email' then c.Data end) as Email
    , max(case when c.Name = 'phone' then c.Data end) as Phone
from AccountContacts ac
left join Contacts c on c.ID = ac.ContactID 
group by ac.AccountID
```

Please realize the reason your struggling here is because your data structure is an anti-pattern known as EAV (entity attribute value). It is a real pain to work with. If at all possible fixing your data structure would be a great plan.

Comment: I totally agree- unfortunately my boss says "live with it for now"

Comment: I was right! Nice to see this, because although I know how to use PIVOT, I got all tangled up with sqlfiddle...lol!

Comment: No need to join to the Contacts table twice.  Join once without filtering by name, and use case statements in the projection: `select ac.AccountID, max(case name when 'email' then data end) email, max(case name when 'phone' then data end) phone from accountContacts ac join Contacts c on c.id = ac.ContactID`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the desired results and the setup provided in your SQL Fiddle, you are looking to PIVOT your data, not UNPIVOT it.

This query does the trick:

```
with src as (
  select accountid
       , name
       , data
    from accountcontacts ac
    join contacts c
      on c.id = ac.contactid
)
select *
  from src
  pivot (max(data)
    for name in ([email],[phone])) pvt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do *conditional* aggregation:

```
SELECT ac.AccountID as ID,
       max(case when c.name = 'email' then c.data end) email,
       max(case when c.name = 'phone' then c.data end) phone
from Contacts c
left join AccountContacts ac on ac.ContactID = c.id
group by ac.AccountID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  select a.data email, b.data phone from  
   (select * from Contacts a 
    join AccountContacts b on a.id=b.ContactID where name='email')a
 full join (
     select * from Contacts a 
     join AccountContacts b on a.id=b.ContactID where name='phone'
  )b on a.AccountID=b.AccountID
```

Comment: This produces the correct results but isn't the most efficient way to deal with this.